# Targetting section on one single page with CSS

Tags: css

I have some tab/blocks on each product page of my site and on one of those pages I am trying to hide the whole section. I am just learning CSS so please pardon my very basic understanding. I was able to remove the whole section with what follows but I cannot figure out how to limit it to just the one page. The post ID for the page in question is .post-id-2193 if that helps.

#wc-tabs-wrapper {display: none;}

hides the tab/blocks on all products pages but no matter how I add the post id I cannot get it to work. Thanks in advance

Perhaps this added info can help id="wc-tabs-wrapper" class=woocommerce-tabs wc-tabs-wrapper

I was able to figure this out .post-2193 #wc-tabs-wrapper display: none; }

Comment: look for outer flanking div element

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide any additional details about your website architecture, for example are you using a specific framework or content management system? Or are you working with raw HTML files?

Without knowing the above, here are some ideas:

If you have the same element recurring on multiple pages, it sounds like maybe `wc-tabs-wrapper` would be more appropriate as a class than as an ID. If you change it to a class it would style the element consistently across the different pages, and then you could create a unique id, eg `wc-tab-post-2193` for that specific element on that specific page.

One alternative would be using Javascript to track the current postId, and setting the display value based on that. But it's hard to give specifics on how to approach this without knowing more about the site architecture.

Comment: Hello and thank you for the reply. We are using WooCommerce. If there is any further details I may provide please let me know.

Comment: Does it allow you to modify the page HTML? If so, do you see where `id="wc-tabs-wrapper"` is defined? If so, you should be able to change it to `class="wc-tabs-wrapper"`, and then add `id="wc-tabs-wrapper-post-2193"` and change your CSS selector to `.wc-tabs-wrapper-post-2193`. Or if this is not clear, if you can add any snippet from your HTML where this is defined, that could help.